# If command, importing .reg not working

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I am trying to use a if command to change language. But all I am getting is "Syntax error"
I really can not find the real syntax.
CMD file

> @echo off
>   echo "1  =Brazilian Portugese"
>   echo:
>   set /p %language%="What language would you like?  "
>   if  "%language%"==1(
>
> > REGEDIT.EXE -s Change Language to Brazilian Portuguese.reg
> >     echo "Language set to Brazilian Portugese"
> >     goto :PAUSE
> >     )
> >     :PAUSE
> >     echo "pausing script"
> >     @pause

Change language to Brazilian Portugese.reg

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Maxis\The Sims 4]
>   "Locale"="pt_BR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try REGEDIT.EXE -s "Change Language to Brazilian Portuguese.reg"**

or use underscores in your file

**REGEDIT.EXE -s Change_Language_to_Brazilian_Portuguese.reg**

For the second part:

```
if "%language%" == "PT" goto PT
PT:
  REGEDIT.EXE -s Change_Language_to_Brazilian_Portuguese.reg
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixes all issues with REGEDIT. But I think I have a problem with my if statements too.

Comment: i'lll add in the answer